# ASP.NET Website Not Displaying Externally for HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, https, external

I have a project that I have developed which is an ASP.NET MVC website.

For a while I have been able to access the website externally but recently when I try to access it at its https domain I get an IIS 7 logo, but http will access the site fine.

However it is a requirement that we use https otherwise I would just stick with http.

There was a dev version of the website that was also able to be accessible both http and https externally and it still works.

(The dev version and the production version used two different subdomains)

I have gone into all settings in the features view under sites in the IIS manager for both the dev version and the production version and made all their settings match and it still won't show externally.

What other areas can I explore?

The OS of the server that the website is server from is Windows Server 2012

Comment: Have you set the https binding in IIS?

Comment: Yeah the bindings match as well. 80 and 443 for both sites

Comment: Is SSL certificate assigned?

Comment: The same certificate is assigned for both subdomains

Comment: Then the only thing remains is NS record.